# Eigen values and vectors calculation error in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to obtain the eigenvectors and values of any matrix 'X' in a specific format. I used the `linalg` function to get the eigen pairs but the expected output format is different from my result. For example, `v` and `e` denote the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. `v1 = 1`, `e1 = [1,0,0]`, `v2 = 2`, `e2 = [0,1,0]`, `v3 = 3`, `e3 = [0,0,1]`.

So in this example, the eigen pairs of matrix X should be `Ep =[(1, [1,0,0])       (2, [0,1,0]),   (3, [0,0,1])]`.
Here `P[0]` represents the first eigen pair `(1,[1,0,0])`, where the eigenvalue is 1, and the eigenvector is `[1,0,0]`.

Can you please help me code this part further?

```
e,v = np.linalg.eigh(X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**np.linalg.eigh**

First, one should note that `np.linalg.eigh` calculates the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix -- this will not apply for all matrices. If you want to calculate the eigenvalues of any matrix `X` you should probably switch to something like `np.linalg.eig`:

```
import numpy as np

L = np.diag([1,2,3])
V = np.vstack(([1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]))

# X = V@L@V.T (eigendecomposition)
X = V@L@V.T

w,v = np.linalg.eig(X)
assert (np.diag(w) == L).all()
assert (v == V).all()
```

**Eigenpairs**

To construct the eigenpairs, just use some list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

# X = V@L@V.T (eigendecomposition)
X = np.diag([1,2,3])

w,v = np.linalg.eig(X)

Ep = [(val,vec.tolist()) for val,vec in zip(w,v)]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi @soyapencil, Thanks for the input. I still get an assertion error with 'w'. assert type(w) == np.ndarray 
AssertionError

Comment: Woops! Some small bugs above. All fixed now.